# Spring batch JSR 352 not rolling back transaction if there is failure in the writer

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I have a writer which takes a list of records and persist the records into 5 different tables. i.e for each record in the list received by writeItems() method there will be 5 insert queries into different tables. Suppose if my batch is processing my first record in the input and inserts record in 2 tables and fails to insert in 3rd table , the records in the first 2 tables are not getting rolled back.

My baseContext.xml file has the following entries

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${batch.jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${batch.jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${batch.jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${batch.jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="${batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle}" />
    <property name="validationQuery" value="${batch.jdbc.validationQuery}" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="${batch.jdbc.defaultAutoCommit}" />
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="${batch.jdbc.removeAbandoned}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="${batch.jdbc.pool.initialSize}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="${batch.jdbc.pool.maxActive}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

I can find my other batch jobs which require to insert into single table are getting rolled back successfully . Request your assistance

Comment: what is your configuration for batch.jdbc.defaultAutoCommit?

Comment: What database?  Are these tables all in the same schema/database?

Comment: I am using oracle database, i set the defaultAutoCommit to false. All tables are in the same database

Comment: @rave763 Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi, I have been in touch Michael Minella, who is the  project lead for Spring Batch. There has been a jira ticket raise dfor this issue , You can find the details below. https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2376. But currently we have not received any fix. Also I have created a sample project to reproduce the issue I was facing , Please feel free to use the project in case you want to reproduce the issue and test it. https://github.com/rbutti/SpringRepository,